# Windows 7 / 8.1 script or batch file that resets network adapter?

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, wifi

I have been doing research trying to create a script of sorts for a off site machine that is running windows 7. It collects weather data and other real time information, but the signal it has cuts out and drops completely, then we have to rive to the site to restore the connection. Is their a way to have a script detect a signal loss then reset the adaptor, or just have a script reset the adaptor ever like 15 min?

This what I currently have:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
arp -d *
nbtstat -R
nbtstat -RR
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Answer (score 0):

If those commands resolve the problem, you could put them in a batch file, e.g., reset.bat, and then schedule the batch file to run every 15 minutes with the schtasks command. E.g., supposing the file is named test.bat and that it is located in C:\users\jdoe, you could use the following command:

```
schtasks /create /tn Reset_Wireless /tr c:\users\jdoe\reset.bat /sc minute /mo 15
```

The `/create` parameter creates a scheduled task, the `/tn` gives it a name, which you can use to delete the task later, if needed, the `/tr` is used to specify the command to execute (include the full directory path), the `/sc minute` specifies that you wish to schedule the task in increments of minutes, rather than hours, weekly, etc., and the `/mo 15` is a modifier value of 15, which because `/sc minute` was specified indicates the task will run every 15 minutes. You can obtain further information on the use of the command by typing `schtasks /?` at a command prompt or by referring to the Microsoft TechNet article [Schtasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx).

If you wished to stop the task from running later, you could use `schtasks /delete /tn Reset_Wireless`. I.e., you would use the `/tn` parameter with the task name you used when you created the task.

Alternatively, for a wireless network connection, you could also try the following in a batch file run as a scheduled task every 15 minutes:

```
netsh wlan disconnect
netsh wlan connect name=profile
```

For the connect command, you will need to provide the relevant profile name for the wireless connection. You can see the available profiles using the command `netsh wlan show profiles`. Note: be sure to match the profile name exactly, i.e., use matching capital and lower case letters to those shown by the `netsh wlan show profiles` command. It is possible that you might not need to include the disconnect command, but only make a connection attempt every 15 minutes.